# Finch: not enough arguments for method 'toService'

Tags: scala, finagle, finch

I've made a pretty simple rest-method using Finch and Finagle:

```
val getUsers:Endpoint[List[User]] = get("users") {Ok(getAllUsers())}
Http.serve(":8080", getUsers.toService)
```

and got this error:

```
Error:(50, 32) not enough arguments for method toService: (implicit ts: io.finch.internal.ToService[List[DAL.Instances.User.User]])com.twitter.finagle.Service[com.twitter.finagle.http.Request,com.twitter.finagle.http.Response].
Unspecified value parameter ts.
  Http.serve(":8080", getUsers.toService)
                               ^
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler error is a little better in the most recent version of Finch (0.10). If we have the following build config:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-core" % "0.10.0"
```

And this setup:

```
import com.twitter.finagle.Http
import io.finch._

case class User(id: String, name: String)

def getAllUsers(): List[User] = List(User("111", "Foo McBar"))
val getUsers: Endpoint[List[User]] = get("users") { Ok(getAllUsers()) }
```

Then when we try to use `toService`, we get the following:

```
<console>:18: error: You can only convert a router into a Finagle service if the
result type of the router is one of the following:

  * A Response
  * A value of a type with an EncodeResponse instance
  * A coproduct made up of some combination of the above

List[User] does not satisfy the requirement. You may need to provide an
EncodeResponse instance for List[User] (or for some  part of List[User]).

       Http.serve(":8080", getUsers.toService)
                                    ^
```

The problem is that you haven't told Finch how to translate instances of your `User` type into HTTP responses. Finch's `EncodeResponse` is an example of a [type class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class), which is an approach to polymorphism that's widely used in Scala (including the standard library) and many other statically-typed functional programming languages.

The easiest way to provide the appropriate `EncodeResponse` instances is to add Finch's [Circe](https://github.com/travisbrown/circe) compatibility module to your build:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "io.circe" %% "circe-generic" % "0.3.0",
  "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-circe" % "0.10.0"
)
```

And then all you need is the following imports:

```
import io.finch.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._
```

And `toService` will work just fine:

```
scala> Http.serve(":8080", getUsers.toService)
Feb 26, 2016 8:32:24 AM com.twitter.finagle.Init$$anonfun$1 apply$mcV$sp
INFO: Finagle version 6.33.0 (rev=21d0ee8b5070b735eda5c84d7aa6fbf1ba7b1635) built at 20160203-202859
res2: com.twitter.finagle.ListeningServer = Group(/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080)
```

Now if you go to `http://localhost:8080/users`, you'll see the following:

```
[{"id":"111","name":"Foo McBar"}]
```

This looks like magic, but what's happening is fairly principled. [Circe](https://github.com/travisbrown/circe) is a JSON library that provides generic codec derivation that figures out at compile-time how to represent your case classes as JSON values (see my blog post [here](https://meta.plasm.us/posts/2015/11/08/type-classes-and-generic-derivation/) for more context).

The [Finch cookbook](https://github.com/finagle/finch/blob/master/docs/cookbook.md) is a great resource for learning more about questions like this, and the first section goes into detail about other ways to provide the `EncoderResponse` instances that `toService` needs. If you have any other questions or if any of the above isn't clear, feel free to ask either here or on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/finagle/finch).

Comment: even after importing io.finch.circe._, io.circe.generic.auto._, scala ide is complaining about  _not enough arguments for method toService:_. any other suggestions?